# How to set/clear multichoice items in alert dialog with custom buttons?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-component, onclicklistener

I make a little android app. In it I need an AlertDialog with multichoice.
But I need custom buttons(when button is clicked, it hides, and we can see another button at this place). I got it.
But when I'm trying to set all multichoice items true by clicking on my custom buttons, I dont know how to do it. Because my custom buttons in their onclicklistener doesn't have

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index, boolean status)
 {                        

 }
```

And I dont know how to get to dialog items.
I hope my question is clear)
Add all my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // AlertDialog.Builder
    adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // multichoice from array and array of checked items
    adb.setTitle("Категории");
    adb.setMultiChoiceItems(category, category_chkd,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                }
            });

    // dialog buttons from category_buttons.xml
    cat_view = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.category_buttons, null);
    adb.setView(cat_view);

    cat_fill_btn = (Button) cat_view
            .findViewById(R.id.category_fill_button);
    cat_clean_btn = (Button) cat_view
            .findViewById(R.id.category_clean_button);
    cat_ok_btn = (Button) cat_view.findViewById(R.id.category_ok_button);


    //AlertDialog
    alert = adb.create();
    //button Ok
    cat_ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.cancel();

        }
    });

    //  button to clear the list
    cat_clean_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            cat_fill_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    // button to fill the list
    cat_fill_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            cat_fill_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });

    return alert;

}
```